# No response on database call (ionic3)

Tags: database, ionic-framework

I try to get a value from a database. It is sensor data, which i want to save from an odroid on the database.

The problem is, I cannot get the value into my ionic 3 app.
The **PHP** file should work, when i open the file, i get the right number in the browser. for testing i also took just a .txt-file with the number 9 inside. but it still doesn´t work. It still stays empty. I have global variables into the provider, which i want to hold up-to-date.

Here is my code:

**global.ts (provider)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable()
export class GlobalProvider {

dif1:number;

constructor(public http: HttpClient){}


load() {

    this.http.get("http://192.168.131.221/test/ultras.1.txt")
    .subscribe((data : any) => {
        this.dif1 = parseInt(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
}

}
```

**data.html (call of the provider)**

```
<button ion-button (click)="global.load()">push</button>
    <div class="llDataContainer">
        <div class="llDataBox llDataBox-2"></div>
        <div class="llDataBox llDataBox-2"></div>
        <div class="llDataBox llDataBox-2">ultra1:</div>

        <!--distance value (ultra1)-->
        <div class="llDataBox llDataBox-2">{{ global.dif1 }} cm</div>
```

If i push the button, still it stays empty.

Comment: What do you mean by 'data.html (call of the provider)'?

Comment: thats just the name of the page. at this page i call the provider, so that i should get the number of the text document. it just don´t work.

Answer (score 0):

the good thing is that i get a response now. the bad thing: the response is NAN...

I tried this:

```
load() {


    this.http.get('url').
    toPromise().then(result => {
    this.dif1 = parseInt(JSON.stringify(result));
})
}
```